# Question about TypeInitializationException

Tags: c#, exception, types, static, initialization

I have noticed something that I quite don't understand. I have `ConfigurationProvider` class which loads configuration values from database and then `Configuration` class which parses them and makes them accessible to the rest of my application. (In reality I parse `xml` configuration but for example I will just replace it with `long`)

```
public class ConfigurationProvider
{
    public static ConfigurationProvider Provider { get; } = new ConfigurationProvider();    

    public string GetParameter()
    {
        // gets configuration parameter from database
    }
}

public class Configuration
{
    public static long Parameter { get; } = long.Parse(ConfigurationProvider.Provider.Parameter);
}
```

In case there is not a valid value in database `TypeInitializationException` will be thrown when accessing `Configuration.Parameter;` then when I change value in database and access `Configuration.Parameter;` again I still get exactly the same exception.

So my question is why is this happening? Can you point me to some documentation of this? As far as I understand `public static long Parameter { get; }` should be initialized only once, once the class `Configuration` is accessed for the first time. But exception makes me feel that this initialization failed and should be performed once again. Or does this mean that `Parameter` actually was initialized and it now references given exception?

ps : I know how to fix this so there is no need for code, I just want to understand this issue better than I do now.

Comment: If the type initializer throws the runtime caches it and rethrows the exception every time the class is accessed. The initializer isn't actually run again.

Comment: Thank you for clarification.